# How can I get docker build to overwrite a file?

Tags: docker, files, copy, copying

It seems that docker build won't overwrite a file it has previously copied. I have a dockerfile with several copy instructions, and files touched in earlier COPY directives don't get overwritten by later ones.

A simplified example (although it also happens if the first copy is an entire directory that happens to contain the file in question):

```
COPY docker/config/file1.yml $BASE/config/thatfile.yml
COPY docker/config/file2.yml $BASE/config/thatfile.yml
```

After building this, $BASE/config/thatfile.yml contains the contents of file1.yml. Is there a way to get it to contain the contents of file2.yml?

My primary use case here is copying a whole folder of config files, and then replacing select config files for specific builds.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue in a recent stable release of docker-ce (19.03.2). I tried both with and without buildkit enabled.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced this too, but after much testing discovered that I had a typo in one of my `COPY` directives' destination paths.

Double-check where those files are really going

```
-COPY nginx.conf /etc/ngnix/nginx.conf
+COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand the behavior of your question. You must have a typo, use a different version, or you have a docker-compose volume which mounts something over something?

https://github.com/bor8/lolquadrat

```
git clone https://github.com/bor8/lolquadrat
cd lolquadrat/
docker build --no-cache .
```

Last output:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM busybox:latest
 ---> 19485c79a9bb
Step 2/6 : ARG BASE=/opt/hihi
 ---> Running in e4a01850931e
Removing intermediate container e4a01850931e
 ---> 193009cc4df9
Step 3/6 : COPY docker/config/file1.yml $BASE/config/thatfile.yml
 ---> bea7783ade65
Step 4/6 : RUN echo 'first thatfile:' && cat ${BASE}/config/thatfile.yml
 ---> Running in 201e86de06bc
first thatfile:
file1content
Removing intermediate container 201e86de06bc
 ---> ca7676a83a16
Step 5/6 : COPY docker/config/file2.yml $BASE/config/thatfile.yml
 ---> da5985cd90fb
Step 6/6 : RUN echo 'second thatfile:' && cat ${BASE}/config/thatfile.yml
 ---> Running in f70153917070
second thatfile:
file2content
Removing intermediate container f70153917070
 ---> 5a4b17a1e77e
Successfully built 5a4b17a1e77e
```

It can be clearly seen that the file `thatfile.yml` has the contents of the second file (`file2content`) after the second COPY command.

The running container shows `file2content` also. To test this, you can make a `CMD tail -f /dev/null` in the last line of your Dockerfile and then go in with `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID_VIA_DOCKER_PS> /bin/sh`. And show the content with `cat thatfile.yml`.

What I haven't fully tested yet is whether the same behavior exists for a folder (instead of `file1.yml`).

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work.

Comment: the snarkiness in this post and comment is extremely uncalled for

Comment: You are right. I removed the snarkiness.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have mounted volume?

```
COPY local_file.txt /directory-in-container/
```

Above does not work, if `/directory-in-container` is a mounted volume.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your case but adding since this is the first google hit for the question.  in my case I was trying:
COPY resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
but was failing since apparently Docker itself will write to this file.